# Where did my Google Reader bundle go?

Tags: google-reader

I had a folder with podcasts on my google reader account and wanted to delete that folder since I read them from another podcast program. I wanted to save them in a OPML file, but I saw that there were a feature called "Create bundle" so I did that on the folder, then I unsubscribed from all the feeds. Now, the problem is that I can't find the bundle back again? Did I lose them by unsubscribing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't deleted the bundle yourself it can be found on **Google bundle creator page**, under the heading

"Your bundles"

http://www.google.com/reader/view/#bundle-creator-page